# Comprehensive handbook of formulas

Tags: big-list

I'm looking for comprehensive, free and online handbook of mathematical formulas, in the form of pdf file. I mainly aim at undergraduate mathematics.

Do you know any link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This I think is exactly what you are looking for:

ftp://ftp.iiap.res.in/aman/EBooks/Schaum's%20Mathematical%20Handbook%20of%20Formulas%20and%20Tables%20--%20301.pdf

Comment: Copy and paste the whole address rather than clicking it otherwise it doesn't work, the whole link wasn't made a hyperlink for some reason.